# Can changing your IP address prevent an NMap attack?

Tags: ip, nmap, network-scanners

If an nmap attacker started a port scan on my network, would changing my network IP address prevent/halt it?

Comment: Technically, yes. It would require them to somehow connect your new address to the old one. Realistically, they will have scanned your entire port range before you can react. And at the risk of being pedantic, scanning isn't an attack per se. It's pre-attack reconnaissance/intelligence gathering.

Comment: This looks like an XY Problem. What is that that you really want to do or what is it that you are really concerned about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing IP address is not a good defense strategy. It's merely evasion and security by obscurity.
The only good strategy is a properly configured firewall + minimizing the attack surface, that is exposing as few services as possible.

You are not saying if this is a LAN or a WAN but the deal is not much different really. In practice the IP address range available is limited, so it's trivial for an attacker to scan the whole range and re-discover your assets. You won't remain hidden for too long.

There are things you can do to thwart port scanning attemtps and frustrate attackers though. Have a look at tools like [CSF+LFD](https://www.configserver.com/cp/csf.html) for example. They will block offenders at firewall level after a certain threshold of port scanning attempts or login failures.
Again, that depends on your circumstances and what you are trying to prevent or protect. Your question should be more focused.

An nmap scan is usually noisy and an IDS should alert you in addition to blocking the attacker. That is precisely what a software IDS such as CSF+LFD does.